# Dividing two numbers out of a integer

Tags: c

I am trying to divide two numbers from an integer(out of a array). The problem is that array must be integers! And I am trying to show a percentage. And as you all know C rounds down so all my answers are zero.

```
float response;
float response1= a[0][1];
float response2= a[0][0];;
response = response1/response2*100 ;
```

This is my solution. Any good idea's on how to improve it ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what's the problem? `response1` is already a `float`, so there's no integer division involved here…

Comment: @SarkoutMahmoud Can you print the values of response1 and response2 (or a[0][0] and a[0][1])? Possibly response1 is very small compared to response2.

Comment: @DanielSiebert no... the code works: [ideone](https://ideone.com/13lZyS). So there is no actual "question" other than "how can I improve my code", which in this case, sounds opinion based and is probably more suited to a review site.

Comment: What do you think about `int percentage = 100 * a[0][0] / a[0][1];`? So you will only loose the decimal digits of the percentage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cast the values:

```
response = (float)(a[0][1]) / (float)(a[0][0]) * 100
```

This accomplishes the same thing as your explicitly introduced variables (and if you need an intergral response, you can wrap this in another layer of casting).

Comment: How is it better than OP's proposal?

Comment: It isn't, really, it may be less cognitive load having explicit casts than having introduced intermediate values (although if they have more meaningful names, the intermediates may help the code be more readable).

Comment: Thanks. I previously used this code without the '(float)' . It did not work !

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
response = ( float )a[0][1]/a[0][0]*100 ;
```

In this case there is no need to create intermediate float variables.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant  At first reread his question. response1 and response2 are not floats.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow No they both are

Comment: @VladfromMoscow How do you think `float response1` declares that variable then?

Comment: Retracting down vote. But how is it better than OP's proposal?